# How to fit an affine transformation which consists of scaling and translation only?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, least-squares, affinetransform

I'm trying to write an app that allows users to georeference an image of a map by clicking waypoints on the map, thereby determining pixel coordinates `x` and `y`, and subsequently clicking on the same waypoint on a 'real' map resulting in a longitude `lng` and latitude `lng`.

I'd like to take it as given that both the image and 'real' map are oriented north-south, so that there is no rotation between them, and also that there is a single scale for north-south and east-west. That is:

```
lng(x) = scale * x + a
lat(y) = -scale * y + b
```

(The reason for the minus sign is that the `y` pixel coordinate increases from the top of the image to the bottom, whereas latitude `lat` increases from south to north).

I've adapted the answer to [how to perform coordinates affine transformation using python? part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546182/how-to-perform-coordinates-affine-transformation-using-python-part-2) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

coords = [
    {"pixel": {"x": 610, "y": 1673}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.66622566136141, "lat": 37.71690293889708}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 3616, "y": 948}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.55987333997541, "lat": 37.739791632115}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 156, "y": 1582}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.68242540789811, "lat": 37.719168689576634}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 1432, "y": 1079}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.63773163590452, "lat": 37.733899511112554}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 1467, "y": 982}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.6365899951677, "lat": 37.73740878429034}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 2045, "y": 464}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.61643210247348, "lat": 37.75263501532096}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 2530, "y": 225}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.59904847563081, "lat": 37.759640099263024}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 3611, "y": 217}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.57440674003465, "lat": 37.769372182124215}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 4218, "y": 289}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.53927620600871, "lat": 37.7590418448261}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 4972, "y": 819}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.51283799895947, "lat": 37.7451015130886}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 4869, "y": 1178}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.5150031101931, "lat": 37.73452849532761}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 4858, "y": 1268}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.51537412573026, "lat": 37.731943969799104}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 4637, "y": 1307}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.52293169964986, "lat": 37.730726899819345}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 4284, "y": 1599}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.53520554208092, "lat": 37.72240153076238}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 4150, "y": 1676}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.53996905111126, "lat": 37.71984653680312}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 3432, "y": 1989}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.56520552108367, "lat": 37.70994983543632}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 2965, "y": 1408}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.58234774459186, "lat": 37.72663636959598}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 2560, "y": 1921}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.59584076119313, "lat": 37.712008849961066}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 1840, "y": 1593}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.6231396666414, "lat": 37.72018991118786}},
    {"pixel": {"x": 1140, "y": 1590}, "lnglat": {
        "lng": -119.64782744839357, "lat": 37.71938854312988}},
]

pixel_coordinates = np.array([[coord['pixel']['x'], coord['pixel']['y']] for coord in coords])
lnglat_coordinates = np.array([[coord['lnglat']['lng'], coord['lnglat']['lat']] for coord in coords])


# Pad the data with ones, so that our transformation can do translations too
n = pixel_coordinates.shape[0]


def pad(x):
    return np.hstack([x, np.ones((x.shape[0], 1))])


def unpad(x):
    return x[:, :-1]


X = pad(pixel_coordinates)
Y = pad(lnglat_coordinates)

# Solve the least squares problem X * A = Y
# to find our transformation matrix A
A, res, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(X, Y, rcond=None)


def transform(x):
    return unpad(np.dot(pad(x), A))


print("Target:")
print(lnglat_coordinates)
print("Result:")
print(transform(pixel_coordinates))
print("Max error:", np.abs(lnglat_coordinates - transform(pixel_coordinates)).max())

print(A)
```

The resulting matrix `A` looks like this:

```
[[ 3.55857577e-05  8.98377941e-07  2.81630741e-18]
 [ 3.43101520e-06 -2.97714115e-05 -8.56519716e-18]
 [-1.19693144e+02  3.77657997e+01  1.00000000e+00]]
```

I would expect it to have the form

```
[[scale 0      0]
 [0     -scale 0]
 [a     b      1]]
```

What I notice is that the independently derived values of `scale` actually differ by ~16% and that the off-diagonal columns which are supposed to be zero aren't.

(In practice, I also notice that the overlay computed with this algorithm is significantly off, as shown below with partial opacity. Note how the roads appear to be shifted to the northwest).

[image]

Is there any way to impose these constraints on the least-squares estimation of the affine transformation - that is, to ensure that the transformation consists of scaling and translation only (no skewing or rotation)?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by following the approach described in these [UC Davis lecture notes](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~yjlee/teaching/ecs189g-spring2015/lee_lecture10_fitting.pdf); I've also described the approach in a [related question on Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336697/how-to-fit-an-affine-transformation-in-which-some-coefficients-are-zero/3337277#3337277).

Suppose you have two waypoints, then the relation between latitude/longitude and pixel coordinates can be expressed as

[image]

(I also realized that the scaling factors for longitude and latitude are different unless you're at the equator). This is of the form `ax = b` described in [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) and we can hence estimate `x` straightforwardly in the least-squares sense.

Here is the code that I used to implement this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Dict
import numpy as np
from cached_property import cached_property


@dataclass
class MapFitter:
    coords: List[Dict[str, object]]

    @cached_property
    def coeffs(self):
        lnglat = np.vstack(tuple(
            np.array([[coord['lnglat']['lng']], [coord['lnglat']['lat']]]) for coord in coords))

        xy = np.vstack(tuple(
            np.array([[coord['pixel']['x'], 0, 1, 0], [0, coord['pixel']['y'], 0, 1]]) for coord in coords))

        coefficients, residuals, rank, singular_values = np.linalg.lstsq(
            a=xy, b=lnglat, rcond=None)

        return coefficients

    def transform(self, xy_coord):
        x, y = xy_coord
        scale_lng, scale_lat, offset_lng, offset_lat = self.coeffs
        return [scale_lng * x + offset_lng, scale_lat * y + offset_lat]
```

So for example, with the same `coords` data structure given in the question, I can do

```
map_fitter = MapFitter(coords=coords)

print(map_fitter.transform([0, 0]))
print(map_fitter.transform([5038, 2027]))
```

resulting in the corner coordinates of the map:

```
[array([-119.68835968]), array([37.7690185])]
[array([-119.51026687]), array([37.70773367])]
```

I also found this to give moderately better alignment of the overlay with the map.